# How to start a new debugging session for a questionnaire website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm going through some code of a questionnaire website. There is a login page, consent page, 5 pages of radio button filled questions, and a thank you page.

I stepped through the code starting from the login page, but whenever I stop debugging and load the web page again for debugging, it always starts from where I left off. How should I have it launch from the first login page? Do I need to clear some saved data from the database or should I clear some caching area?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the questionaire is saving the last completed in a cookie.

Try opening an incognito window and pasting the URL from the debug session or deleting the cookies.

Comment: Turns out I had to delete some stuff from a database. Thanks! @_@